# How to tell if user clicked Cancel when calling MSI functions?

Tags: c++, windows-installer

My installer bootstrap app makes a bunch of MSI calls at the start in order to get information from the MSI (what version(s) are installed, what features are installed, property values, paths, etc.). While these MSI calls are being made, Windows installer throws up a window with a Cancel button on it. My code has traps everywhere to check if the error code returned by an MSI call is ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT so that the bootstrap app can stop if the user clicks Cancel, and yet all I ever see for the return value, even when I know for sure that I had managed to click the Cancel button (I actually see the button get depressed), is ERROR_SUCCESS.

Is there any way to tell, with 100% certainty, whether or not the user clicks on Cancel while those MSI calls are being made? If not, is there a way to hide that Cancel button during the MSI calls so the user is not lulled into a false belief that he can cancel at that time? (On a fast machine, this isn't much of an issue, as the dialogue goes away rather quickly, but on a slow machine, the user actually has a chance to click the button.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you're getting small "Preparing you install" style dialogs. If that's the case, what you want to do is preface your calls with [MsiSetInternalUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370389%28VS.85%29.aspx) to hide all (or most) UI. Note that if you then call [MsiInstallProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370315%28VS.85%29.aspx) or similar to kick off the install, you may need to restore a non-silent UI level.

If I misread your question, and instead you're talking about custom actions, the only place your code can find out about a user canceling things is via the return code from [MsiProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354%28VS.85%29.aspx), and that's also the API you'd use to disable the cancel button.

Comment: Thanks. While a bit extreme, it did achieve what I was after, mainly to get rid of that Cancel button since I can't seem to get a reliable means to determine whether or not it was clicked.